# Samba-shared DeskJet 420C prints gibberish test page

Tags: printer

Setting up one Ubuntu wireless client laptop (old Dell I wiped clean) on otherwise XP home network.  Finally got laptop to print to XP host's LPT1 cable-connected Hewlett-Packard Deskjet (also vintage) after much fiddling with the "Windows printer via Samba" setup option.  Had to use host's IP address instead of name to make anything happen at all.  It was great to hear the old printer come to life, but all it prints is garbage characters and streaks in about the same places as a Ubuntu test page.  Have not tried to print anything else.

This Deskjet prints perfectly when jobs are sent to it from all the other wired/wireless clients in our house, so I thought it might be a driver issue.  Have since tried all 3 driver choices offered in Ubuntu "new printer" setup listing.  Even downloaded/installed Hewlett-PackardLIP package from LinuxPrinting.org with no change.

This Linux client prints fine to a newer Linux-ready Hewlett-Packard Officejet, but that setup was far more hassle-free, probably because it's hooked directly to the router via ethernet cable and doesn't involve the host.  I've messed with lots of computer hardware and even built a few, but am very new to Linux.  Just trying to squeeze some more life out of solid older equipment.

Anybody have ideas on what else to try? I am familiar with typing some commands in "Terminal" after installing the wireless adapter card, but that took a lot of time and effort to get right and I'd like to avoid doing that again!